How do I render different parts of a line on a line, depending on the category, with different colors?
now my code is here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ECharts Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.3/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #main {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<script>
    const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

    option = {
        title: {
            text: 'Distribution of Electricity',
            subtext: 'Fake Data'
        },
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis',
            axisPointer: {
                type: 'cross'
            }
        },
        toolbox: {
            show: true,
            feature: {
                saveAsImage: {}
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            // prettier-ignore
            data: ['00:00', '01:15', '02:30', '03:45'  ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value',
            axisLabel: {
                formatter: '{value} W'
            },
            axisPointer: {
                snap: true
            }
        },
        visualMap: {
            show: false,
            dimension: 1,
            categories: ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'],
            inRange: {
                color: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
            },
            outOfRange: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Electricity',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                // prettier-ignore
                data: [[100, "type1"],
                    [200, "type2"],
                    [300, "type3"],
                    [400, "type4"]]
            }
        ]
    };


    myChart.setOption(option);
</script>
</body>
</html>

when run this code, it will occor a error like
echarts.min.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coord')
at gS (echarts.min.js:45:338543)
at e.render (echarts.min.js:45:341108)
at t.progress (echarts.min.js:45:166893)
at t._doProgress (echarts.min.js:45:135412)
at t.perform (echarts.min.js:45:134984)
at echarts.min.js:45:216047
at e. (echarts.min.js:45:116287)
at Array.forEach ()
at E (echarts.min.js:35:5071)
at e.eachSeries (echarts.min.js:45:116207)

At present, there is only an example of determining the color according to the value range of the y-axis, this is the official links https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=line-sections.
Is someone nice to help me solve this problem?

Your current code colors the points, not the line segments. The error is not related to the visualMap, but is caused by the fact that you don't have an x-axis mapping; if you set data as: data: [[0, 100, "type1"], [1, 200, "type2"], [2, 300, "type3"], [3, 400, "type4"]], and change dimension: 2 in the visualMap, there will be no error, see fiddle.

If you want to color the segments, why isn't the solution in the example you linked to convenient? In any case, it is not clear how you want to color the line by category since the segments are between categories, so in the example above there are 4 categories, 4 points, but only 3 segments. Maybe you want the color to change halfway (on x axis) between the points? Please add an indication (possibly an image) of what your expected result is.
